# replace period in form field on submit

Tags: javascript, php

I am working with a payment system that wants the amount output as cents.

To avoid confusion I want my clients to be able to input with a decimal e.g. 123.45 instead of 12345 . How can I replace the period on submit so that the format is correct? I have tried to implement onclick javascript but don't seem be be getting th syntax or positioning right.

The form as, as is is here:

```
<form action="https:/….Default.aspx" method="post"> 

<table> <tbody> 
<tr> 
<td>Client Reference:</td> 
<td><input name="orderid" type="text" value=" " /></td> 
<td>e.g. Smith 2017</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Amount in euros:</td> \<td><input name="amount" type="text" value=" " /></td> 
<td>please put the amount in cents instead of using full stop (.) e.g. 12356 instead of 123.56</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td><input type="submit" value="Pay" /></td>
 <td></td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table> 

<input name="currency" type="hidden" value="EUR" /> 
<input name="windowstate" type="hidden" value="3" /> 
<input name="merchantnumber" type="hidden" value=“012345 />    
</form>
```

The javascript I have been playing with is

```
onsubmit = “removeperiod()”

<script type = "text/javascript">

function removeperiod() {

var str = “amountenter”
str = str.replace(/./,””); 
amountenter = str;  // write the de-accented string back into the form field.
}
</script>
```

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Why not, on the backend, just divide the amount they enter by 0.01?

Comment: Highly recommend doing this on the server side, as your client may turn javascript off.  Other than that, you need to escape the period.  `replace(/\./,"")`

Comment: All you need to do is multiple by 100.

Comment: @nerdlyist LOL, I'm not sure why I went for the divide suggestion. Multiply is easier :)

Comment: @JeremyHarris I was the one that upped yours then was like wait a second...

Comment: Could you jsfiddle it please? it will be easier to understand your unformated code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of expecting your users to put the amount needed in cents, and then removing the decimal if they do it in euros, why not expect your users to put the amount needed in euros, then convert that into cents?

Ideally you should handle this conversion at the server; fix the server code (or tell whoever manages it to fix it) so that it can take an input and dollars then convert it to cents itself

If this isn't possible, then you can do it using JS. But you'll have to tell your clients they need to enable js. Replace the below code

```
<td>please put the amount in cents instead of using full stop (.) e.g. 12356 instead of 123.56</td>
```

with something like

```
<noscript>Please enable JS, or put the amount in cents instead of using full stop (.) e.g. 12356 instead of 123.56</noscript>
```

And then intercept the submit and convert this value to cents via `onsubmit`; add the `onsubmit` attribute (and an id to get the text element) to your `<form ...>` tag with:

```
<form action="https:/….Default.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="prepareToSubmit" id="form">
```

and then implement the conversion in `prepareToSubmit` function like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function prepareToSubmit() {
    var amountElement = document.getElementById("form").elements["amount"];

    //Converts value from euros to cents
    amountElement.value = Math.round(amountElement.value * 100);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If javascript is turned off, the incorrect value will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this both: server side and client side.
For the client side try with something like this:

```
function removeperiod() {
    var str = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    str = str.replace(".",""); 
    document.getElementById("amount").value = str;
    return true;
}
```

Note that you must use **id** instead of **name** in your form fields.